# Heroku can't find libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm running through a ruby on rails tutorial, and I just installed the Heroku toolkit.

My problem is that whenever I try "Heroku login", or whatever heroku command, I get :

```
ruby1.9.1: error while loading shared libraries: libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I remember having cleaned my ruby installations recently, so I wonder if I just miss some libs that I have deleted or something, but I haven't been able to find anything satisfying about that.

Do you have an idea how to get out of this situation, and be able to use Heroku ?

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you using a ruby manager like chruby?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu. I use rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make heroku work by installing it with gem :

```
gem install heroku
```

instead of :

```
sudo apt-get heroku
```

It seems like heroku was trying to use a ruby version out of rvm (but i deleted the ruby version which was installed before rvm). Now the gem installation took care of that.